# How to apply props/ mask(like snapchat) on face using real camera in swift?

Tags: camera, frameworks, face-detection, vision, snapchat

I am working on a snapchat like app where user will be able to apply filters on his face or multiple faces. Minimum iOs support is iOS 12 , device support : iPhone 6 & above. Please let me know how to implement this.